# Cannot read property 'members' of undefined, while trying to execute command

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

Code:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id !== bot.user.id && !member.user.bot);
  member.send(message);
});
```

If anyone knows what is the problem, it would be helpful to know

Error:

```
(node:2076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: Done. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: It does, your title says `members is undefined` when the error says that it can't read property `members` of `undefined`, which means `message.guild` is undefined.

Comment: Can you show how you defined `message`?

Comment: bot.on("message", async message => {
//code
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably that it's receiving messages outside of a guild, like in a dm channel.

most people don't allow dm messages when coding bots to being with, if you want to do that just return at start

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
});
```

Otherwise wrap your code around an if statement

```js
if(message.guild) {
  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    if (member.id !== bot.user.id && !member.user.bot);
    member.send(message);
  });
}
```

Could be better ways to do this depending on your other code.